# How do I integrate a menu into a layout (Java GUI)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, menu

I am trying to add a menu to this program, but I am having trouble with it.  I think the code for the menu itself is okay, but I cannot figure out how to actually insert it into my GUI.  In this project I have 4 classes.  One for some JRadioButtons, one to add a large text field, one for the menu, and then one final one to put it all together.  When I run the program without the menu class, this is the output.[Output of program without menu class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2MFi.png)

Here is some of the code as well.

```
JRadioButton encrypt1 = new JRadioButton("Reverse Word" );
JRadioButton encrypt2 = new JRadioButton("+1");
ButtonGroup group1 = new ButtonGroup();

JRadioButton decrypt1 = new JRadioButton("Reverse Word");
JRadioButton decrypt2 = new JRadioButton("+1");
ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();

public chooseEncryption(){
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 4));

    panel1 = new JPanel(); panel2 = new JPanel(); panel3 = new JPanel();
    panel4 = new JPanel(); panel5 = new JPanel(); panel6 = new JPanel();
    panel7 = new JPanel(); panel8 = new JPanel(); panel9 = new JPanel();
    panel10 = new JPanel(); panel11 = new JPanel(); panel12 = new JPanel();

    encryptionLabel = new JLabel("Encryption");
    decryptionLabel = new JLabel("Decryption");
    group1.add(encrypt1);
    group1.add(encrypt2);
    group2.add(decrypt1);
    group2.add(decrypt2);

    panel2.add(encryptionLabel);
    panel4.add(decryptionLabel);
    panel6.add(encrypt1);
    panel8.add(decrypt1);
    panel10.add(encrypt2);
    panel12.add(decrypt2);

    add(panel1); add(panel2); add(panel3); add(panel4); add(panel5);
    add(panel6); add(panel7); add(panel8); add(panel9); add(panel10);
    add(panel11); add(panel12);
}
```

That's the radio button class, and then I integrate it using this putTogether class.

```
public putTogether(){ //Constructor of putTogether class
    setTitle("Encryption Program");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    panel = new chooseEncryption(); //object of radio button class
    panel2 = new textField(); //object of text field class


    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

And here is part of the menu class.

```
public class menu extends JFrame{

    public void buildMenuBar(){
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        buildFileMenu();
        buildEditMenu();
        buildHelpMenu();

        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }
```

How would I set up the menu so that it becomes part of the GUI.  I know it has something to do with creating a constructor for it, but I haven't been able to make any progress.  I appreciate the help on this!

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html). Download the working code and modify it for your requirement. The working code will show you how to properly create the class to you don't extend JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Use cardLayout.
How to use card layout - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Hope! it helps.